# ajax function what to put in url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-select

sorry for asking such a basic question, but i am new to ajax and i couldn't find a documentation (i dont even know the name of this ajax syntax).i understand other parts of this code snippet but i don't know what am i supposed to put in the url part of the $.ajax function. please help

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="docSpec" id="docSpec">
        <option value="Pulmonary" selected="selected">Pulmonary</option>
        <option value="Physician">Physician</option>
        <option value="General">General</option>
        <option value="Cardiologist">Cardiologist</option>
        <option value="pediatrics">pediatrics</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

js:

```
function do_something() {
    var selected = $('#docSpec').val();
    $.ajax({
        this part-- > url: '/you/php/script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            value: selected
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#my_div').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the javascript! by the way, i am trying to get a selected option value from a `<select>` ("supposedly on change as a trigger") without having to submit the form.

Comment: In the URL part, you list the php page for you that handles your code. So if you bring a variable from your form, you need to proces it on another page, but AJAX handles this without loading additional pages. It does require the page, but it just runs in the background, and you wont notice. So in that php file, you execute your `select / update / insert into` statements

Comment: so, in default, not initializing this results in the default being the page where this was executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected value of the `<select>` using

```
 $('#docSpec').val();
```

You don't need to use ajax for that. Changing the selected option of a `<select>` will not trigger form submission or reload the page by default.

You can get the value when it is changed using the `change()` method:

```
$('#docSpec').change(function(){
  alert(this.value); // You can access the new value here
});
```

Comment: as an additional question my humble sir, is there an ideal place i can insert this snippet to? or should i just replace what i already have? thanks for answering the root cause of my problem!

Comment: yes, add it inside `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ // code goes here}); </script>` to make sure the script runs after the elements are created... you can read more [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)